# Adding product to cart - variable assignment django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the function of adding products to cart.
However, it doesn't work as it should.
The first time you add a product to cart, you always add 1 when you add the quantity of the product. After you add and add value again, everything works fine.

**product.html**

```
        <div class="float-right">
        <form action="{% url 'cart:add_cart' product.id %}" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="float-left">
          <input type="number" value="1" name="quantity" class="form-control" style="width: 100px">
        </div>
          <input class="btn send-click btn-md my-0 p" type="submit" value="Add to cart">
          </form> </div>
```

**views.py**

```
def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
                cart_id = _cart_id(request)
            )
        cart.save()
    try:
      cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
      if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
        if request.method == 'POST':
          quantity = request.POST['quantity']
          cart_item.quantity += int(quantity)
      cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
      cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
                  product = product,
                  quantity = 1,
                  cart = cart
          )
      cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

There is error on this line `quantity = 1` I have no idea what to assign instead of this 1.

**Edit:**

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Product

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Cart'
        ordering = ['date_added']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cart_id

class CartItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CartItem'

    def sub_total(self):
        return self.product.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

**Edit: Solution:**

```
quantity = request.POST['quantity'],
```

**views.py**

```
def add_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(
                cart_id = _cart_id(request)
            )
        cart.save()
    try:
      cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
      if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
        if request.method == 'POST':
          quantity = request.POST['quantity']
          cart_item.quantity += int(quantity)
      cart_item.save()
    except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
      cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
                  product = product,
                  quantity = request.POST['quantity'],
                  cart = cart
          )
      cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

Comment: This is often when the `CartItem` has a required field (without a default) that you forgot to pass to the `.create(..)` call.

Comment: I have no idea what to assign to quantity to make it work as it should.

Comment: please attach the model structure and error detail you get

Comment: I attached the models.py structure. The error is rather logical. The first time you add a product to cart, you always add 1. Despite entering a different value. Once this product is in the basket and I add a value of e.g. 20, it works.

Answer (score 0):

add `force_update=True` argument in line here `cart_item.save(force_update=True)`

```
def add_cart(request, product_id):
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
        try:
            cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        except Cart.DoesNotExist:
            cart = Cart.objects.create(
                    cart_id = _cart_id(request)
                )
            cart.save()
        try:
          cart_item = CartItem.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
          if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
            if request.method == 'POST':
              quantity = request.POST['quantity']
              cart_item.quantity += int(quantity)
          # add argument force_update=True (because this query to update quantity field)
          cart_item.save(force_update=True)
        except CartItem.DoesNotExist:
          cart_item = CartItem.objects.create(
                      product = product,
                      quantity = 1,
                      cart = cart
              )
          cart_item.save()
        return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

you can to try this code for simple exception, i hope this logic to success.

```
def add_cart(request, product_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

        cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(cart_id=_cart_id(request))

        cart_item = CartItem.object.filter(product=product, cart=cart)
        if cart_item.exists():
            if cart_item.quantity < cart_item.product.stock:
                quantity = request.POST['quantity']
                cart_item.quantity += int(quantity)
                cart_item.save(force_update=True)
        else:
            CartItem.objects.create(
                product = product,
                quantity = 1,
                cart = cart
            )

    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```